# Error pushing Ruby on Rails to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have added the pg and rails_12factor gem to my gemfile and tried to push my app to heroku but the website just says application error, I was able to do this successfully a few weeks ago by following what I think were the same steps. I have made a small test app just to recreate this error, here's the output when I try to push to heroku:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 336 bytes | 336.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.4
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
remote:        Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled 
properly.
remote:        This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your 
app.
remote:        In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your 
dependencies at all.
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path 
vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
remote:        The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of 
the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but 
the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To 
add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-
mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.     
remote:        Resolving dependencies...
remote:        Using rake 12.3.0
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
remote:        Using minitest 5.11.3
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Using builder 3.2.3
remote:        Using erubi 1.7.0
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
remote:        Using crass 1.0.3
remote:        Using rack 2.0.4
remote:        Using nio4r 2.2.0
remote:        Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
remote:        Using mini_mime 1.0.0
remote:        Using arel 8.0.0
remote:        Using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Using execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Using method_source 0.9.0
remote:        Using thor 0.20.0
remote:        Using ffi 1.9.21
remote:        Using multi_json 1.13.1
remote:        Fetching pg 0.17.1
remote:        Using puma 3.11.2
remote:        Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
remote:        Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
remote:        Using rb-fsevent 0.10.2
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.8
remote:        Using turbolinks-source 5.1.0
remote:        Using i18n 0.9.3
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.5
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.8.2
remote:        Using websocket-driver 0.6.5
remote:        Using rack-test 0.8.2
remote:        Using sprockets 3.7.1
remote:        Using mail 2.7.0
remote:        Using uglifier 4.1.5
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
remote:        Fetching rails_12factor 0.0.2
remote:        Using turbolinks 5.1.0
remote:        Using activesupport 5.1.4
remote:        Using loofah 2.1.1
remote:        Using sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.4.1
remote:        Using activemodel 5.1.4
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.7.0
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using sass 3.5.5
remote:        Using activejob 5.1.4
remote:        Using activerecord 5.1.4
remote:        Using actionview 5.1.4
remote:        Using actionpack 5.1.4
remote:        Using actioncable 5.1.4
remote:        Using actionmailer 5.1.4
remote:        Using railties 5.1.4
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
remote:        Using rails 5.1.4
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.7

remote:        Installing pg 0.17.1 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rails_12factor 0.0.2
remote:        Bundle complete! 15 Gemfile dependencies, 59 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.

remote:        Bundle completed (9.84s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Removing pg (1.0.0)
remote:        Removing rails_12factor (0.0.3)
remote:        The latest bundler is 1.16.1, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
remote:        To update, run `gem install bundler`
remote: -----> Installing node-v6.11.1-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
remote:        Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
remote:        Asset precompilation completed (1.55s)
remote:        Cleaning assets
remote:        Running: rake assets:clean
remote:
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
remote:        Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
remote:        This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
remote:        In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
remote:
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        No Procfile detected, using the default web server.
remote:        We recommend explicitly declaring how to boot your server process via a Procfile.
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
remote:
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, web, worker
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 37.4M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v9
remote:        https://coolguygear.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/coolguygear.git
   69e3355..ce67809  master -> master

C:\Users\Jared\testapp>
```

Heres the Heroku Logs:

```
2018-02-07T16:22:53.750068+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=coolguygear.herokuapp.com request_id=12882767-fed0-4354-b265-1d06931b22eb fwd="100.14.28.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2018-02-07T16:25:18.468191+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=HEAD path="/" host=coolguygear.herokuapp.com request_id=09ea1016-ba0c-4d77-8a71-92cd0388874d fwd="34.229.222.142" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-07T16:27:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user pagaley12@outlook.com
2018-02-07T16:27:43.618675+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-02-07T16:27:43.286746+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 32766c38 by user pagaley12@outlook.com
2018-02-07T16:27:43.286746+00:00 app[api]: Release v11 created by user pagaley12@outlook.com
2018-02-07T16:27:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-02-07T16:27:47.302392+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 24230 -e production`
2018-02-07T16:27:52.402259+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283395+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283421+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283420+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.1.4 application starting in production
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283486+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:188:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283509+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:185:in `spec'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283423+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283534+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:58:in `establish_connection'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283527+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:880:in `establish_connection'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283537+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `instance_eval'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283536+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283541+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283544+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283539+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283542+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283546+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283552+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:326:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283550+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283555+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283557+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283553+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283561+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283562+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283564+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/application_record.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283566+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283570+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283574+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283572+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283583+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283577+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:379:in `block in require_or_load'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283579+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:36:in `block in load_interlock'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283587+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:149:in `exclusive'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283592+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:36:in `load_interlock'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283590+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283596+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:357:in `require_or_load'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283599+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:335:in `depend_on'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283605+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:476:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283603+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require_dependency'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283609+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283628+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `block in eager_load!'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283635+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:67:in `each'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283630+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `each'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283631+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `eager_load!'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283633+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:354:in `eager_load!'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283638+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283637+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:67:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283644+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283645+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283642+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283647+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283649+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283652+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283654+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283660+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283663+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283656+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283669+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283661+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283667+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283672+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283682+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283674+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283688+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:in `new'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283678+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283695+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283684+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283691+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:in `<main>'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283741+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283746+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283737+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283739+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283748+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:24:in `app'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283750+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283752+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.4/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in `start'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283755+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:44:in `start'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283763+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283762+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `block in perform'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283837+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283838+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283767+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283840+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283849+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283845+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283847+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283851+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.283852+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2018-02-07T16:27:52.418583+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-02-07T16:27:55.488508+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=coolguygear.herokuapp.com request_id=1b71ed89-fe54-437d-b13d-082c848c328c fwd="100.14.28.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2018-02-07T16:27:55.831207+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=coolguygear.herokuapp.com request_id=cc0e8bf6-f754-4ba2-be25-4e924afe0b71 fwd="100.14.28.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2018-02-07T16:27:56.485232+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=coolguygear.herokuapp.com request_id=e2530067-459c-4fea-a62e-7029fef88952 fwd="100.14.28.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2018-02-07T16:27:56.568374+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=coolguygear.herokuapp.com request_id=4d909fee-121c-4086-9060-5abb0531f9bd fwd="100.14.28.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2018-02-07T16:27:57.266204+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=coolguygear.herokuapp.com request_id=77ba5529-63bd-4257-9ee1-106c3f34d353 fwd="100.14.28.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2018-02-07T16:27:57.348456+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=coolguygear.herokuapp.com request_id=b4846660-d494-47c2-982a-626635621b69 fwd="100.14.28.68" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify a specific pg version in your gemfile. If not, you will be using the latest available version (1.0.0). But this version is still not supported by Rails. Check here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31673

Yous should use version 0.21

```
gem 'pg', '0.21'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the command *heroku logs* to print  output of rails server? You might find something useful to the problem you have.

Comment: I can't find anything there other than the bottom where it just says error and some other stuff I don't understand

Comment: Include gem ‘pg’ in your gemfile. You required postgresql as an adapter to database but you didn’t include it in your gemfile.

Comment: I have it int here, its in the production group

Comment: Your error message says you don’t have one. Maybe the version is wrong?