# hey I am trying to deploy a rails app on heroku, and i get the follow error message when i run git push heroku master

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

```
    remote:        
    Gem::LoadError: 
    **strong text**Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the 
     gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its 
      version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
```

I have this loaded in the gem file:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

    git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
   repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?
    ("/") "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
    end
```

Gems:
        gem 'jquery-rails'
        gem 'active_model_serializers', '0.10.6'
        # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
        gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.3'
        # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
        # Use Puma as the app server
        gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
        # Use SCSS for stylesheets
        gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
        # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
        gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
        # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported 
        runtimes
        # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

```
    # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
    # Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read 
    more: 
    https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
    gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
    # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: 
    https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
    # Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
    # gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
    # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
    # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
    gem 'nokogiri'

    # Use Capistrano for deployment
    # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

    group :development, :test do
    # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a 
    debugger console
    gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
    # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
    gem 'selenium-webdriver'
    end

    group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    end

    group :development do
     # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console 
     %> anywhere in the code.
    gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
    gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
    # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running 
    in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
    gem 'spring'
    gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
    end

    # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-
    data gem
    gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
    gem 'devise'
    gem 'omniauth-facebook'
    gem 'flash'
    gem 'pry'
```

^^End of Gem File

I ran bundle install -without production. And this does not work. Not sure where I am going wrong here.

Comment: Can you post your entire gem file on master?

Comment: Remove gem ‘sqlite3’ and add gem ‘pg’ instead you can’t install gem sqlite3 on heroku

Comment: I have added my entire Gemfile Anthony

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error pushing Ruby on Rails to heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668466/error-pushing-ruby-on-rails-to-heroku)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku with rails 5 error Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264765/heroku-with-rails-5-error-gemloaderror-specified-postgresql-for-database-ad)

Answer (score 0):

Specify the version of pg in your gemfile. I was once receiving the same error and this line worked for me.

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
```

instead of just gem 'pg'

Answer (score 0):

Move the line

```
gem 'pg'
```

outside
`group :production`

so the gem will be installed in any type of environment